# "Tu n’as aucun accent" or "Tu n’as pas aucun accent"?

Tags: grammaire, négation

I am reading a beginners book to learn French. Somewhere in the book there is this sentence:

> Tu n’as aucun accent !
>   *You have no accent!*

My question is, shouldn't it be "Tu n'as **pas** aucun accent !" instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Words

*ne + pas* is the most standard negation indeed, *but* pas can be replaced with another word. For instance, you have *ne + aucun*, *ne + jamais* (*Je ne suis jamais allé à Disney Studios.*), *ne + personne* (*Heureusement, il n'a blessé personne.*), …

#### Adding *pas* to your example

This is just incorrect. An English approximation of this would be "You **don't** have no accent!" It might be the contrary of your meaning in an inelegant way, or just a plain mistake (though I understand the question).

As the OP remarked, this English form, though not being taught when learning English as a foreign language, exists in informal speech in some parts of the US. The French form, though, is incorrect everywhere as far as I am aware.

#### English equivalents

These are just examples, far from an exhaustive list. Please note they are not rules and may depend on context

- *ne + pas* = not
- *ne + aucun* = not any
- *ne + plus* = not anymore
- *ne + jamais* = not ever/never
- *ne + personne* = not anybody
- …

Comment: I would translate "You **don't** have no accent" instead of "You have **not** no accent", nope ?

Comment: Thank you for you response. Let me add though that, as far as I know, "You don't have no accent" or "You ain't have no accent" is acceptable among some American people in informal speech.

Comment: @Random Correct! I changed my mind as I first thought of "You have no any accent."

Comment: @Meysam Correct too, but it is not taught as being English. Thanks for the note, I will integrate it in the answer.

Comment: Are these two equivalent? "Tu n'as pas accent" vs "Tu n’as aucun accent"? Would it have the same meaning if I used the first one?

Comment: @Meysam Yes, they are mainly equivalent. There might be a slight nuance between the two, something like "_Tu n'as pas d'accent._" being "You don't have any accent." and "_Tu n'as aucun accent._" being "You don't have _any_ accent." Note the _d'_ in "_ne + pas_". I will not elaborate upon this here, but there are other questions on tis site about it.

Answer (score 3):

[*Normal use*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14860) no longer allows *pas/point* with *aucun, nul, jamais, rien, personne* or *guère* to express a single negation. A reason for that is that such words have gained a negation meaning over time and cancel themselves out when used in such combinations (*ce n'est pas rien/ne... pas... que*). It is even more intricate as in some cases you can have such one negation being used positively in a negative context (viens-tu *pas* demander asile ? (Hugo)) and further cases where it is considered more acceptable (*Il ne recommandait pas de tuer personne au nom de cette suprématie* (Henriot)); the latter usually involving the use of a preposition or the second auxiliary being used as a complement. This should also be distinguished from cases where two negations are close but apply to different verbs (je ne vois *pas* cependant qu'*aucun* ait blâmé... (Brunot)) and therefore don't constitute a double negation.

But those restrictions may not apply to *popular speech* (*je n'ai pas rien trouvé*, attested) and therefore you may hear something such as the "*tu n'as pas aucun accent*" you mention, albeit not in a beginner's book geared at learners. You may also find it in more classical work :

> Je n'ai *pas* besoin d'*aucune* preuve (Claudel)
>  Cette collection
>   comme aucun prince n'en possède pas à l'heure actuelle (Proust)

There used to be a time when you could have combinations which are no longer normally allowed; the *ne* element carried over the whole negation and what followed had basically no impact over it : L'i de cette particule [=si] ne se mange *point* devant *aucune* des cinq voyelles (Vaugelas).<sup>1</sup>

---

<sub>1. All examples and content adapted from *Le bon usage* (Grevisse et Goosse, ed. *Duculot*) §§ 1019, 1021.</sub>

Comment: Very interesting, especially about history. I never encountered cases such as _je n'ai pas rien trouvé_ and I guess everybody I know would understand this as _mes recherches n'ont pas été vaines_. You say it is attested; do you have more information about it for my own education?

Comment: OK, on a donc une notion de régionalité dans ce type d'usage. C'était surtout cette info que je cherchais. Merci. :)

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use **pas**, the correct French sentence is

> tu n'as pas d'accent.

**d'** is added, because

- “tu n'as pas accent” would make a hiatus (double 'a' sound)
- “tu n'as pas de accent” would make a double wowel 'de' 'a'

Comment: The hiatus is not the cause here. Consider "_Tu n'as pas de cheveux._"

Comment: There is no hiatus in "tu n'a pas accent" since you pronounce the "s" of "pa**s**"...

Comment: @Random you don't pronounce "tu n'a pas z_accent" !!

Comment: @Archemar you do... why not ? You always pronounce it in front of a vowel...

Comment: note that it is "tu as" instead of "tu a". I cannot edit because there are only 3 characters.

Comment: @Archemar I concur with Random: though not mandatory, nothing forbids a liaison here. "_Je n'ai pas (z)un sou._" The next vowel being a A does not change anything, unless I am mistaken.

Comment: @Archemar The problem might be with *tu n'as pas accent* itself rather than with the liaison... This structure is not common in France at all. #Chop The syntactic context plays a major role in determining whether liaison can take place or not. The phonological context (following vowel) is just a small part of the equation.